# USSD Request will not show any response for a certain short code

Tags: at-command, modem, ussd, telecommunication

I am using a SIM Modem accessed via Putty from my windows pc. Everything works fine, I can send at commands and receive results for example `AT+CUSD=1,"*133#",15` will return `+CUSD: 0,"You have 3,596 IQD, valid until 30-06-2021.",15` even other ones show a list of options. But only one certain command that directly asks for a pin code is not returning any result.

I have tried the same code with the same SIM Card on an android phone and it work fine, I have looked at other similar questions and no one has the same problem as mine. Is there any command to activate secure USSD responses? I am literally lost I don't even know what to ask for other than why I don't get a response for one certain short code?

Comment: You have posted an example of a working USSD command but omitted to post the one that didn't work. Furthermore, USSD codes are operator-dependant. Which SIM operator are you using?

Comment: The one that doesn't work is `AT+CUSD=1,"*327#",15` this short code asks for a pin code after you enter it. @RobertoCaboni

Comment: And what is the operator? (USSD codes are operator dependant)

Comment: The company that provides the USSD service for the operator is called Seamless Distribution Systems. I can't find any other details about their stuff.

Comment: Could you link the guide containing the list of the USSD commands you tried (and hopefully their descriptions)?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni thank you for the hassle but my problem is that they provide no guide.

Comment: I needed it in order to write a proper answer, just to confirm what ai suspect the solution is. Usually PIN codes have to be written in the same command in the format `*777*<your pin>#`. Realistic just providing the command (in this example `*777#`) triggers the choice menu presentation.

Comment: I have tried that option even before asking the question. Even when I try `*<short code>*<pin code>#` on a phone it returns `Connection problem or invalid MMI code.`